# How to disable syntax highlighted text in the codemirror editor?

Tags: css, html, text, syntax-highlighting, codemirror

I need to disable the syntax highlighted text in the codemirror editor since the user may edit some syntax in the editor which will cause the program not to run. So, how to disable the syntax content from editing?

For example:
[image]

In this , Only the tags should not be editable rest of the content should be editable.

How to do it??

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
readOnly: boolean|string
This disables editing of the editor content by the user. If the special value "nocursor" is given (instead of simply true), focusing of the editor is also disallowed.
```

Visit: http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html for docs

Comment: Could you please add you're output scrren

Comment: I have added an expected output in the question

Comment: For the user,only that region should be ediable,When they run, the whole content of the editor will be taken as program to run. I need it because the end user should not edit the syntax of the program.

Comment: Well, I don't think that giving privilege to run PHP Script by universe, is safe.

Comment: I think,you have misunderstud my question.I have added a screenshot pls let me know if you don't understand fully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68315/discussion-between-gaurav-dave-and-vidhya-raju).